# UISwitch puts on UILabel event doesn't work

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios7, xcode5

I encounter a problem is that I need a formatted grid which contain serious of UISwitch, and my solution is to put those UISwitches on each UILabel .

However, these switches can't operate normally. Any suggestions?

Below is my code:

```
-(void) drawSummaryColumn : (UILabel *) myLabel :(NSString *) title
{
    NSArray *sHeaders = @[NSLocalizedString(@"Tue", nil),
                          NSLocalizedString(@"Wed", nil),
                          NSLocalizedString(@"Thu", nil),
                          NSLocalizedString(@"Fri", nil),
                          NSLocalizedString(@"Sat", nil),
                          NSLocalizedString(@"Sun", nil),
                          NSLocalizedString(@"Total", nil)];
        float basizSize  = myLabel.frame.size.width;

        CGRect r;
        CGRect pos;

        pos.origin.x =8;
        pos.origin.y = 3;
        UILabel *firstCol = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
        r.origin.x =0.5;
        r.origin.y =0.5;
        r.size = CGSizeMake(120, 40);
        firstCol.text =title;
        firstCol.font = [ UIFont fontWithName :@"Georgia-Bold" size : 17];
        firstCol.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        firstCol.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
        firstCol.frame =r ;
        [myLabel addSubview:firstCol ];

        basizSize -= 120;
        basizSize = (float) basizSize / 7;

        for (NSString *label in sHeaders)
        {

            UISwitch *objSwitch = [[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
            objSwitch.frame = pos;
            [objSwitch addTarget:self action:@selector(switchAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
            UILabel *columns = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
            columns.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
            columns.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
            [columns addSubview:objSwitch];

            r.origin.x += r.size.width + 0.5f;
            r.size = CGSizeMake(basizSize, 40);
            columns.frame =r ;
            [myLabel addSubview:columns];
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
myLabel.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

firstCol.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

columns.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

by default, a label's userInteraction property is false. Hence all it's subviews(including uiswitch) has this property set to FALSE initially. parent view (uilabel) needs to have this property ENABLED so that it's subviews also get enabled for user interaction.

Comment: You are adding firstCol label to myLabel label and UISwitch to myLabel, Is it something you want to do? I would recommend you to create subclass of UIView and add grid of your switches.

Comment: Outstanding!!! Work great!! 
And the I will reference Greg's way, I think my solution isn't a nice way!

Comment: I'd like to upvote your answer, but I need 15 reputation @@
I will as quick to upvote it as I archieved that point ^^
Thanks a lot really!!!